# What e4 opening for an ELO below 1000?

Tags: opening

As a player with an ELO below 1000, what e4 opening would you recommend I focus on, the Italian game, Giuoco Piano or the Ruy Lopez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Brian that you should focus on as tactical openings as possible until you get to at least 1600. In general don't worry too much about the openings at this stage, tactics are for you right now much more important.

Focus on opening principles:

1. Control of the center (*e4*, *d4*, *e5*, *d5* squares)
2. Development of the pieces (as close to the center as safe)
3. Finding safe place for your king (castling)

However, I think that there are a lot of suitable lines for you in the Italian complex.

For example, **the Møller attack**:

**1. e4** you put a pawn in the center and open up lines for development of your light squared bishop and queen.

**1. ... e5** your opponent does the same.

**2. Nf3** you develop your knight and attack *e5*, gaining time.

**2. ... Nc6** your opponent develops his knight and at the same time defends *e5*.

**3. Bc4** you point your bishop at the weakest point in your opponent's camp - *f7*. This pawn is weak, since it's only protected by the king.

**3. ... Bc5** your opponent does the same. He can also try **3. ... Nf6**, the two knight defence, where older lines with **4. d4** will server you well.

**4. c3** you are preparing to play **d4**, aiming for total central control.

**4. ... Nf6** your opponent pressures your *e4* pawn and develops his knight.

**5. d4** you don't need to defend *e4*! Your development is good enough that your priority is opening up lines for attack. This comes with tempo on bishop.

**5. ... exd4** your opponent goes for few exchanges, aiming for **Nxe4**, winning a pawn.

**6. cxd4** preserving your center, renewing threat on bishop.

**6. ... Bb5+** your opponent moves bishop to safety with check.

**7. Nc3** but this doesn't harm your development, you develop your other knight, blocking the check.

**7. ... Nxe4** your opponent finally wins a pawn, but this losses time and your good development guarantees you good play in exchange.

**8. O-O** you break bishop pin, put your king to safety, and prepare **Re1**.

**8. ... Bxc3** your opponent tries to exchange a few pieces, thus lessening your attack.

**9. d5!** increasing tension in the center, gaining space, disorganizing your opponent pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with "none of the above" but I go further: Don't study openings yet.

If you start with 1. e4 there's the Sicilian, the Caro, the Petroff, and more, in addition to 1. ....e5.  And, since you are under 1000, your opponents are probably also under 1000. You will be out of book very early and, whatever opening you play, you won't know what to do. It's true that it may be harder to figure out in "strategic" openings than "tactical" ones .... But that goes for your opponent too!

So, play. If you like the idea of (say) the Danish gambit (which I'd prefer to the King's gambit) then fine. Do that. But don't learn a lot of opening theory. Play games and go over them slowly using a computer and an opening data base (the one o chess dot com is fine for now). Ideally, go over them with a coach (but that can get expensive).

Learn tactical puzzles (tons of sources). Learn some strategic ideas, too. Strategy isn't just for masters!  I don't like this notion that beginners should *just* do tactics. OK, your strategy won't be like Hikaru's. Nor will your tactics. At first, your strategy will stink, but so will your tactics. But good tactics often come from good positions.

I also suggest looking at the speed runs of really good players against beginners. I especially like Daniel (Danya) Naroditsky's speed runs. Of course he crushes beginners, but he explains what is going wrong in their games. I think this is more useful than studying games between GMs. Those guys are fighting over things that you and I may never understand but that's both tactical and strategic.

(Danya also posits that beginners and intermediates can play any opening, including the deepest.)

I also suggest not playing too much blitz and not playing bullet at all. Play slow games.

Comment: Seconding recommendation of Danya Naroditsky. Chesscoach Andras on YouTube is also excellent and has big focus on opening principles for begineers.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above.

Much stronger players than you have little chance of understanding these mostly strategic openings. At just over 1800 FIDE I include myself in this.

At your level the biggest gains will come from improving your tactical play. The best openings for this would be the Kings Gambit against 1...e5 and the Morra Gambit against 1...c5. Concentrate on these two first.

You will have lots of quick wins with these openings (as well as lots of quick losses). Importantly, you will easily understand what happened, why you won or lost, and you will understand the basic idea - fast development aimed at the enemy king followed by checkmate. And the games will be fun. Ruy Lopez and Italian games will not be much fun.